# How come Kotlin's built-in "lazy" function actually works?

Tags: kotlin, delegates, lazy-initialization

I wanted to try something new with delegated properties in my Kotlin code. What I found in docs is that for custom delegated properties I need to create a class with obligatory methods - `getValue` and optionally `setValue`, which are part of interfaces mentioned in the docs:

> You can create delegates as anonymous objects without creating new classes using the interfaces `ReadOnlyProperty` and `ReadWriteProperty` from the Kotlin standard library

I started digging through Kotlin's built-in delegate functions. I looked into implementation of `lazy` function which looks like following:

```kotlin
public actual fun <T> lazy(initializer: () -> T): Lazy<T> = SynchronizedLazyImpl(initializer)
```

And here's where my question stands: **Why does it actually works?** `Lazy` interface has only `value` property and some method determining its initialisation of the value. `SynchronizedLazyImpl` doesn't have much more than this. None of them have `getValue` or `setValue` methods, so why Kotlin doesn't complain and compiles successfully?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source for `Lazy` [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Lazy.kt), you can see the following on line 37:

```kotlin
/**
 * An extension to delegate a read-only property of type [T] to an instance of [Lazy].
 *
 * This extension allows to use instances of Lazy for property delegation:
 * `val property: String by lazy { initializer }`
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun <T> Lazy<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value
```

Essentially, there's a `getValue` extension function for `Lazy` instances that just returns the `value` property. `SynchronizedLazyImpl` just defines the `value` property, and `getValue` is automatically provided.

Comment: Ahh, the extension function. Never thought I could see them with for interfaces. Nice catch,m thank you!